# Sync sent mail with Sent folder

Tags: c#, email, outlook, mapi, cdo.message

I need to sync sent mails with the sent folders of mail servers, for the users to see at future moments. I can send mails using all these 3 ways, SMTP, CDO and Microsoft Outlook Object(**MOO**); out of which I can only see my sent mails with MOO. Now the problem is, Not all clients are using outlook, and thus its more impractical to use this.

Out of exercise, I had also used MAPI to send mails, but that don't send HTML body. Also I looked over this topic [Microsoft Sent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25900131/microsoft-sent-folder), but that don't solve my problem.

So is there anyway, I can send mail with HTML body and sync the sent mail with Sent Folder. ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi), but you probably mean Simple MAPI.

If you are connecting to an Exchange mailbox, EWS is another option.